# How to component query a grid?

Tags: javascript, extjs, gridview, extjs4

I want to query a grid that has no id or itemId associated with a extension window. Is there a way to do it?

Here's how you do it with an id. but how to do it without one?

```
var yourGrid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('yourGridID')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`query`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.container.Container-method-query) from a parent container (or [`down`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.mixin.Queryable-method-down) that seems more appropriate for what you want to do), and the xtype of your target component -- as explained in the top of the doc for [`Ext.ComponentQuery`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery-method-query).

So, given something like this:

```
var ct = new Ext.Container({
    // ...
    items: [{
        xtype: 'grid',
        // ...
    }
    // ...
    ]
});
```

You'd do:

```
var grid = ct.down('grid');
// or
var grid = ct.query('grid')[0];
```

Note that this would also work, as long as you've got only one grid in your whole application:

```
var grid = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('grid')[0];
```

Comment: Well, I do have one grid on the main page, but once I click a button, it brings up another window.Window which has the grid with no id/itemId. I need to return the text on the grid in that window.

Comment: In that case, your parent container is the window (`myWin.down('grid')`). However, it seems that you're doing something wrong, why don't you want to give your grid an itemId?

Comment: cos that grid is just using data from the first grid, I just want to compare if those data show correctly on the grid in the other window.